# Zend switch between database

Tags: php, zend-framework, datamapper

In my ZEND (2.3) project I have a datamapper to connect to a MySQL database. But this specific website is running on two databases. One MySQL database and one Solar database. Based on a variable `$solarOnline` I need to get the data from the MySQL database or from Solar.

I have it all working with just the MySQL database. The structure of the model is:

```
src\
  Blog\
    Model\
      Post\
        Post.php
        DataMapperInterface.php
        Exception.php
        Factory.php
        IdentityMap.php
        IdentityMapFactory.php
        MySQLDataMapper.php
```

Now I think I need to add an extra datamapper, called `SolarDataMapper.php` to the `Post` directory and in this file add the communication functions for Solar.

But how would I be able to switch between the `MySQLDataMapper` and the `SolarDataMapper`?

Can I do something like this in the `DataMapperInterface.php`

```
<?php
namespace Blog\Model\Post;

global $solarOnline;

if($solarOnline){
  interface DataMapperInterface{
    public function fetchSolarPostById($id);
  }
}else{
  interface DataMapperInterface{
    public function fetchPostById($id);
  }
}
```

Or is there another way to get this done? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, I fixed my own issue!

In the file `IdentityMapFactory.php` I already had a function `createService()`. This function returns a IdentityMap. Now I let it return 2 IdentityMaps.

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
    return new IdentityMap(new MySQLDataMapper(), new SolarDataMapper());
}
```

In `IdentityMapAbstract.php`

```
abstract class IdentityMapAbstract {
    protected $_dataMapper;
    protected $_dataMapperSolr;
}
```

In construct of `IdentityMap.php`

```
public function __construct(DataMapperInterface $dm, DataMapperInterface $dm1){
        $this->_dataMapper = $dm;
        $this->_dataMapperSolr = $dm1;
        return $this;
    }
```

And in the already existing function `fetchPostById($id)`

```
private function fetchPostById($id) {
        if($this->solarOnline) {
            $value = $this->_dataMapperSolr->fetchPostById($id);
        }else{
            $value = $this->_dataMapper->fetchPostById($id);
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

of course I created a file called `SolrDataMapper.php` with it's solr functions

Comment: just change your logic in creating your service ``createService(){ if($solr){//solr}else{//mysql}`` so the mapper is in all classes the same and don't need to be changed or extend with a ``solrmapper``

Comment: That's true, but MySQL and Solr must exist simultaneously. Maybe that's not quite clear in my question.

Comment: ok so between two updates in one request lifecircle the mapper can be different? if so you can tell the servicemanager that you need a new instance every time you call it, the the createService is called everytime you call the service. i think this is cleaner then edit all the classes and for update purpose

Comment: No, specific search function functions are executed by Solr, simple request by MySQL.

Comment: ah ok now i got it, yeah then you need two mapper in one lifecircle